# What does ‘a woman with seriously good hair’ mean? Is “Good Hair” primarily applied to American-African ladies?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

Further to my question about the use of ‘MFF’ on New York Times article ( Jan.29 ) titled “As State of the Union Nears, Congress Plays Musical Chairs,” I have a question about the meaning of the phrase of ‘members of the Senate with seriously good hair’ in the following sentence:

> Mary from Louisiana asked Olympia from Maine because they are BFFs, but had a backup in Bob from Tennessee in case she was rebuffed. Kirsten from New York went the Sadie Hawkins route and asked John from South Dakota, and thus the deal between two members of the Senate with seriously good hair was sealed.

I was intrigued by the phrase, ‘good hair,’ in the above sentence. So I checked Urbandictionary to find its real meaning and found the following definition:

> A popular term in the African-American community, used to describe a black person's hair that closely resembles the hair of a typical white person (i.e. soft, manageable, long, as opposed to "nappy" or "bad" hair). The closer your hair is to a white person's, the "better" your hair is.

I was confused. On YouTube, both Sen. Marry L. Landriey and Olympia Snowe are clearly white, one with bland and another dark hair. Is Urbandictionary’s definition - 'used to describe a black person's hair' wrong? What does "Senators with *seriously good hair*” really mean? Is it a praise or does it involve sarcastic insinuation?
Please teach me.

Comment: Just to let you know, Urban Dictionary is not necessarily a good source. I can't speak for this particular definition, but I'd be very wary of relying on anything it says if writing in a professional manner.

Comment: I'm wary of anything on UB, period.  For whatever purpose.  But that goes for any other source too.  Okay, more so for UB. ;-)

Comment: This expression is unique to American English, I'll say that much. (We don't use it here in Britain.) Also, I second the distrust of Urban Dictionary!

Comment: Same here. A better bet is the *American Heritage Dictionary*: http://dictionary.reference.com/help/ahd4.html

Comment: waiwai and jae. O.K. Forget about Urbandictionary's definition which I understand can be simply contributions of laymen.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Actually, there is truth to the Urbandictionary definition you provided. I mean, within the AA context, *good hair/awesome hair/nice hair* would mean hair that is not natural/tightly curled (or coiled)/nappy. But *good hair* is used everywhere to mean nice-looking hair. Sometimes, even natural black (African) hair is considered *good/awesome* if it looks great, e.g. well-groomed Afros, natural locks, etc.

Comment: waiwai and jae. O.K. Let's forget about Urbandictionary's definition which I understand can be simply contributions of laymen. Ignoring what Urbandictionary says, however, what is the intent of New York Times writer by saying in such particular way as 'the deal between two members of the Senate "with seriously good hair" was sealed? (I saw both women's hair and hair style on the Senate floor and interviws on youtube, but neither didn't look so seriously impresseve hair and hair style as compared with those of models of Unilever hair rinse commercials for me personally). That's I want to know.

Comment: In the article, the comment about "good hair" refers to Senator John Thune and Kirsten Gillibrand, not to Marry Landriey and Olympia Snowe: "Others who have paired off include Senators Kirsten Gillibrand ... and John Thune ... generally considered two of the more well-coiffed and attractive members of the Senate."

Comment: Jae, Jimi Oke, Noldrin. I understand all of you don't trust UB. So I checked the American Heritage Dictionary jimi recommended.

Comment: Jae, Jimi Oke, Noldrin. I understand all of you don't trust UB. So I checked the American Heritage Dictionary jimi recommended. It defines 'good hair' as '( Caribbean ) hair showing evidence of some European strain in a person's blood.' It's not saying 'good hair'is used to describe a black person's hair' as UD does. Still American Haritage Dictionary's definition doesn't seem to include 'seriously' blond and brunette. So again what's the meaning of the deal between two members of the Senate 'with seriously good hair' was sealed?

Comment: @Yoichi Just to let you know, the definition of "good hair" you found at the Urban Dictionary was not wrong, and neither was the one given to you in the accepted answer; two different classes of people, journalists and African-American women, use the same phrase to describe different things.   You've gotten the other definition already, but let me make the Urban Dictionary definition more transparent to you: "Good hair", when used by an African-American women, would refer to the sociological fact that many men, and thus consequently women, in that community...

Comment: ..prefer European-style straight hair in the feminine sex, over the natural "kinky" style of hair that it is more typical of African ancestry. That preference is lambasted by some, because they consider it "colorism" and part of the legacy of unfair European cultural domination -- those African-Americans with straighter hair would tend to be those with more European ancestry, and thus lighter skin.  Their cultural advantage, in being more likely to be described by commentators as "beautiful" or "attractive", stemming in part from the perceived quality of their hair, is seen by some as unfair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Good hair" is kind of a meme in American English. (I was going to say *faux meme*, but no one would forgive that pun.) TV announcers and politicians all strive to have good hair.

[image]

[Picture source](http://crooksandliars.com/2007/10/24/mitt-romney-mistakenly-refers-to-osama-bin-laden-as-barack-obama)

Scott Adams' comic strip *Dilbert* calls this "executive hair" and this has entered the [political vocabulary](https://mises.org/freemarket_detail.aspx?control=108), at least. People with "good hair" seem to have it all over those who don't. Especially those who don't have any hair at all. Just ask [Larry David](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YGjuRYEguI) (watch the whole clip).

The opposite of good hair is, of course, bad hair. Americans even speak of "having a bad hair day" when nothing seems to be going right with their appearance (or their day) in general.

Comment: Robusto. Thanks for clear answer accompanied with a pursuasive visual presentation. ITSUMO OSEWANINARIMASU. ARIGATOU GOZAIMASU.

Answer (score 7):

The whole article is sarcastic and borderline absurdist, comparing the functioning of a legislative body to a children's game of musical chairs, and then attributing childish attributes to the participants (such as being "BFFs", an abbreviation of the childish idea of "Best Friends Forever", and "going the Sadie Hawkins route", referring to a dance in which traditional roles are reversed and the girl/woman asks the boy/man).

In this case, the "good hair" comment is meant to highlight the lack of depth (in intellectuality or, perhaps, moral character) of the participants, as if having "good hair" were somehow an important characteristic for people in high leadership positions. In the context provided, the author may not have meant it as personal criticism directed toward the individuals, but just as an overall sarcastic comment on the proceedings.

In any case, "African Americanism" had nothing to do with the comment. It is true that the phrase "bad hair" (and presumably its opposite, "good hair") first gained currency among the African American community, but it has long since passed into general usage.